# Scheme-DrRacket-BSL Don't understand my error message and its reason

Tags: scheme, racket

```
; TASK-1

; Length is a Number.
; interp. length of a letter in cm.

; Width is a Number.
; interp. width of a letter in cm.

; Height is a number.
; interp. height of a letter in cm.

; Weight is a Number.
; interp. weight of a letter in g.

; Format is one of:
;  - "Standard"
;  - "Kompakt"
;  - "Gross"
;  - "Maxi"
; interp. the products offered by Deutsche Post

(define (function-1 Format)
  (cond
    [(string=? "Standard" Format) ...]
    [(string=? "Kompakt"  Format) ...]
    [(string=? "Gross"    Format) ...]
    [(string=? "Maxi"     Format) ...]
    [else ...]))

; MaybeFormat is one of:
;  - Format
;  - #false
; interp. the best Format choice, or #false if no Format would work

(define-struct MaybeFormat (Format boolean))
; A MaybeFormat is a structure: (make-MaybeFormat Format boolean)
; interp. either a Format or #false


; MaybeFormat -> String or boolean
; decides whether it's a Format or a boolean (#false)

(define (function-2 MaybeFormat)  
  (cond
    [(MaybeFormat? MaybeFormat) ...]
    [else ...]))


; TASK-2

; Length Width Height Weight -> MaybeFormat
; find the cheapest format to send something
(check-expect (cheapest-format 14     9    0.5      20) "Standard")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 23.5   12.5 0.5      20) "Standard")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 10     7    1        50) "Kompakt")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 23.5   12.5 1        50) "Kompakt")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 14     9    0.5      50) "Kompakt")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 10     7    2       500) "Gross")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 35.3   25   2       500) "Gross")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 10     23.5 1       500) "Gross")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 10     7    5      1000) "Maxi")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 35.3   25   5      1000) "Maxi")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 10     7    2      1000) "Maxi")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 10     7    5        10) "Maxi")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 35.3   7    1        50) "Gross")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 14     25   0.5      20) "Gross")
(check-expect (cheapest-format 50     9    0.5      20) #false)
(check-expect (cheapest-format 10     50   1        50) #false)
(check-expect (cheapest-format 10     9    500      20) #false)
(check-expect (cheapest-format 10     9    1      9001) #false)
(check-expect (cheapest-format 0      0    0         0) #false)
(check-expect (cheapest-format 0      9    2        20) #false)
(check-expect (cheapest-format 10     0    0.5      50) #false)
(check-expect (cheapest-format 10     9    0        20) #false)
(check-expect (cheapest-format 10     9    0.5       0) #false)

(define (cheapest-format length width height weight)
  (cond
    [(format-possible? "Standard" length width height weight)
     "Standard"]
    [(format-possible? "Kompakt" length width height weight)
     "Kompakt"]
    [(format-possible? "Gross" length width height weight)
     "Gross"]
    [(format-possible? "Maxi" length width height weight)
     "Maxi"]
    [else
     #false]))


;TASK-3


; Format Length Width Height Weight -> Boolean
; check whether we can send something as a given format
(define (format-possible? format length width height weight)
  (and (in-range? length (min-length format) (max-length format))
       (in-range? width (min-width format) (max-width format))
       (below-maximum? height (max-height format))
       (below-maximum? weight (max-weight format))
       (above-minimum? (aspect-ratio length width)
                       (min-aspect-ratio format))))


; Maximum is a Number.
; interp. the upper bound of something

; Minimum is a Number.
; interp. the lower bound of something


; in-range?
; Number Minimum Maximum -> Boolean
; Check whether a number is between a minimum and a maximum
(check-expect (in-range? 5   0   10) #true)
(check-expect (in-range? 50  8   42) #false)
(define (in-range? number Minimum Maximum)
  (cond
    [(>= number Minimum) #true]
    [(<= number Maximum) #true]
    [else #false]))

; above-minimum?
; Number MaybeMinimum -> Boolean
; Check whether a number is above an optional minimum
(check-expect (above-minimum? 42 13) #true)
(check-expect (above-minimum? 35 99) #false)
(define (above-minimum? number sMaybeMinimum)
  (cond
    [(>  number sMaybeMinimum) #true]
    [(<= number sMaybeMinimum) #false]))

; below-maximum?
; Number Maximum -> Boolean
; Check whether a number is below a maximum
(check-expect (below-maximum? 10 15) #true)
(check-expect (below-maximum? 42 10) #false)
(define (below-maximum? number Maximum)
  (cond
    [(<  number Maximum)#true]
    [(>= number Maximum)#false]))

; min-length
; Format -> Minimum
; return minimum length of a format
(check-expect (min-length "Standard") 14)
(check-expect (min-length "Maxi")     10)
(check-expect (min-length "Kompakt")  10)
(check-expect (min-length "Gross")    10)
(define (min-length Format)
 (cond
   [(string=? "Standard" Format) 14]
   [(string=? "Kompakt"  Format) 10]
   [(string=? "Gross"    Format) 10]
   [(string=? "Maxi"     Format) 10]))

; max-length
; Format -> Maximum
; return maximum length of a format
(check-expect (max-length "Standard") 23.5)
(check-expect (max-length "Maxi")     35.3)
(check-expect (max-length "Kompakt")  23.5)
(check-expect (max-length "Gross")    35.3)
(define (max-length Format)
   (cond
   [(string=? "Standard" Format) 23.5]
   [(string=? "Kompakt"  Format) 23.5]
   [(string=? "Gross"    Format) 35.3]
   [(string=? "Maxi"     Format) 35.3]))

; min-width
; Format -> Minimum
; return minimum width of a format
(check-expect (min-width "Standard")  9)
(check-expect (min-width "Maxi")      7)
(check-expect (min-width "Kompakt")   7)
(check-expect (min-width "Gross")     7)
(define (min-width Format)
    (cond
   [(string=? "Standard" Format) 9]
   [(string=? "Kompakt"  Format) 7]
   [(string=? "Gross"    Format) 7]
   [(string=? "Maxi"     Format) 7]))



; max-width
; Format -> Maximum
; return maximum width of a format
(check-expect (min-width "Standard") 12.5)
(check-expect (min-width "Maxi")       25)
(check-expect (min-width "Kompakt")  12.5)
(check-expect (min-width "Gross")      25)
(define (max-width Format)
    (cond
   [(string=? "Standard" Format) 12.5]
   [(string=? "Kompakt"  Format) 12.5]
   [(string=? "Gross"    Format)   25]
   [(string=? "Maxi"     Format) 25]))

; max-height
; Format -> Maximum
; return maximum height of a format
(check-expect (max-height "Standard")  0.5)
(check-expect (max-height "Maxi")        5)
(check-expect (max-height "Kompakt")     1)
(check-expect (max-height "Gross")       2)
(define (max-height Format)
    (cond
   [(string=? "Standard" Format)  0.5]
   [(string=? "Kompakt"  Format)    1]
   [(string=? "Gross"    Format)    2]
   [(string=? "Maxi"     Format)    5]))

; max-weight
; Format -> Maximum
; return maximum weight of a format
(check-expect (max-weight "Standard")   20)
(check-expect (max-weight "Maxi")     1000)
(check-expect (max-weight "Kompakt")    50)
(check-expect (max-weight "Gross")     500)
(define (max-weight Format)
    (cond
   [(string=? "Standard" Format)   20]
   [(string=? "Kompakt"  Format)   50]
   [(string=? "Gross"    Format)  500]
   [(string=? "Maxi"     Format) 1000]))


; AspectRatio is a Number.
; interp. ratio of length to width

; aspect-ratio
; Length Width -> AspectRatio
; compute aspect ratio of letter
(check-expect (aspect-ratio 50   10)      5)
(check-expect (aspect-ratio 23.5 12.5) 1.88)
(check-expect (aspect-ratio 35 7)         5)
(define (aspect-ratio Length Width)
  (/ Length Width))

; min-aspect-ratio
; Format -> MaybeMinimum
; return optional minimum aspect ratio of format
(check-expect (min-aspect-ratio "Standard")   1.4)
(check-expect (min-aspect-ratio "Kompakt")    1.4)
(check-expect (min-aspect-ratio "Gross")   #false)
(check-expect (min-aspect-ratio "Maxi")    #false)
(define (min-aspect-ratio Format)
      (cond
   [(string=? "Standard" Format)   1.4]
   [(string=? "Kompakt"  Format)   1.4]
   [(string=? "Gross"    Format)#false]
   [(string=? "Maxi"     Format)#false]))



; MaybeMinimum is one of:
;  - #false
;  - Minimum`
; interp. the lower bound of something, or #false if there's no lower bound

(define (maybe-minimum-template maybe-minimum)
  (if (false? maybe-minimum)
     ...
     (... maybe-minimum ...)))
```

When I run this code it gives me the following error:
">: expects a real as 2nd argument, given #false"

I do not understand why. When I isolate the function which is supposed to generate the error it works flawlessly. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`min-aspect-ratio` returns a boolean for "Gross" and "Maxi". Therefore in `format-possible?`, the test `(above-minimum? (aspect-ratio length width) (min-aspect-ratio format))` fails.

I am not familiar with BSL but these changes should help:

```
(define (aspect-ratio Length Width)
  (if (zero? Width)                          ; <=====
      #false                                 ; <=====
      (/ Length Width)))                      

(define (above-minimum? number sMaybeMinimum)
  (cond
    [(boolean? number) number]               ; <=====
    [(boolean? sMaybeMinimum) sMaybeMinimum] ; <=====
    [(>  number sMaybeMinimum) #true]
    [(<= number sMaybeMinimum) #false]))
```

No more errors but 20 of the 60 tests fail.

Comment: Ahh, I see, thanks.

Do you have any suggestions about how I could try to avoid that and implement it in another way? Feeling a little bit lost at the moment..

Comment: It's hard to answer without any context. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to write a program which determines which format is the cheapest for a customer who is trying to send a letter.

so the customer enters the length, width, and mass of the thing he wants to send and the function returns which format is the cheapest option or whether he can't send that item at all.

prices and data are taken from here:
https://www.deutschepost.de/de/b/brief_postkarte.html

hope I made my intentions more clear

Comment: @Zeth Don't you just want to replace `#false` with `0` for those cases? (Zero would be the smallest possible ratio, I believe. And impossible to attain.)